# Racket Handin Image Error

Tags: image, scheme, racket

I'm running the Racket Handin Server: http://docs.racket-lang.org/handin-server/index.html

Students submit functions that output images. I'm trying to test a function called pinwheel that they've submitted.

I'm getting the below message on the student report and I'm unsure why. It may deal with the student language is beginner and the server language is not and they are using different image=?. However, I'm unsure.

> image=?: expects type  as 2nd argument, given: (object:image%
>   ... (overlay (translate 0 0 (overlay (translate 0 0 (polygon (list
>   (pulled-point 0 0 0 0 0 0) (pulled-point 0 0 10 0 0 0) (pulled-point 0
>   0 10 30 0 0) (pulled-point 0 0 0 30 0 0)) 255 "blue")) (translate 10
>   10 (translate 30 0 (polygon (li...; other arguments were:
>   (object:image% ...)

This is my relevant code in my checker.rkt:

```
(module checker handin-server/checker

  (require handin-server/grading-utils)
  (require 2htdp/image)
  (require (only-in lang/htdp-beginner
                    [image=? compare-images]))

  ....
  (check:
   :language 'racket
   :requires '(bsl-plus-image)                                                     
   :create-text? #f
   :textualize? #f

   ;;pinwheel---------------------------------------
   (@test "pinwheel case 1"
          "Incorrect pinwheel function"
          (pinwheel (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))
          (above (beside (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue") (rotate -90 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))
                 (beside (rotate -270 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")) (rotate 180 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))))
          (lambda (x y) (compare-images x y))
         1)       

   ))
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what the error is? The code expected value's code is the correct solution. If I run this locally within a student's file's check-expect there is no problem:

```
(check-expect (pinwheel (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))
              (above (beside (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue") (rotate -90 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))
                     (beside (rotate -270 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")) (rotate 180 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))))
```

I would like to further note that there seems to be something weird going on even when I do the following the test fails saying that the expected and actual are not the same:

```
;;pinwheel---------------------------------------
       (@test "pinwheel case 1"
              "Incorrect pinwheel function"
              (above (beside (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue") (rotate -90 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))
                     (beside (rotate -270 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")) (rotate 180 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))))
              (above (beside (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue") (rotate -90 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))
                     (beside (rotate -270 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")) (rotate 180 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))))

             1)
```

I may not know enough racket to solve this by myself. Let me know if there's any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my proposed solution. Essentially, in order to compare the images, the easiest way is to handle it in the test case. In order to handle it in the test case, you will need to define a variable that stores the expected value using eval! which evaluates the expression in the submitted file's language.

For the record, the bsl-image package can be created using the following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/twViz38AL7M

```
(module checker handin-server/checker

  (require handin-server/grading-utils)
  (require 2htdp/image)

  (sandbox-path-permissions
  (cons
    (list 'read "/")
    (sandbox-path-permissions)))
  (define assignment-name "testing")


   ;Checks that submission is on time and that the user has submissions left
  (pre:
   (check-deadline)
   (check-max-submissions))

  ; Ends the report by adding the score and writes it in the user directory
  ; This way, students can see their reports from the web interface.
  (post:
   (add-score-to-report!)
   (write-report))

  (check:
   ; Get timestamp of the submission and add it to header and report
   :language 'racket
   :requires '(bsl-plus-image)                                                     
   :create-text? #f
   :textualize? #f

   (update-submission-timestamp!)
   (add-header-line! (get-submission-timestamp))
   (add-report-line! (get-submission-timestamp))


    (with-handlers ([exn?
                         (lambda (exn)
                           (message (format "~a will be accepted, but...\n~a"
                                            assignment-name (exn-message exn))
                                    '(ok)))])

   ; Initialize max score
   (set-test-max-score! 78)

   ;;pinwheel---------------------------------------
   (!eval (define expected-pinwheel2 (above (beside  (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue") (rotate -90  (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue")))
                                            (beside (rotate -270  (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "red")) (rotate 180  (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))))))
   (@test "pinwheel case 1"
          "Incorrect pinwheel function"
          (equal? (pinwheel (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "blue"))
                  expected-pinwheel2)
          #t
          1)

      )

   ))
```